# How to create PayPal website payment pro sandbox account?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, website-payment-pro

I was trying to make website payment pro sandbox account. I followed all instructions (from my sellers sandbox account applied for website payment pro, clicked on "save and continue" button after entering all information) but I am getting blank page from PayPal as response.

Does anyone know how to create Paypal Payments pro in Sandbox account ?

Comment: Can you please share the code you have with us?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Go to https://developer.paypal.com/ and login using a valid PayPal account.

1. Click on 'Dashboard'
2. Click on 'Accounts' under the 'Sandbox' heading

Use the following values:
Country: United States
Credit card: Visa
Bank account: No
Balance: Up to you
Password: Use something easy to remember

Create the account and retrieve the API credentials by clicking on the little arrow on the left of the account. Click 'Profile' followed by 'API Acess' in the modal window that opens up.

Comment: I have created "Buy Now" through Website Payment Pro. For Payment
I have selected "Don't have a PayPal account?". Entered test credit card no. and real email address of my Gmail account.
I am getting error  "You cannot use an e-mail address or card number that belongs to an existing PayPal account. If you have a PayPal account, please log in. If you don't, please change the e-mail address or card number and try again." 

I want to do payment through credit card not by PayPal account.Please help. :Jyoti

Comment: That's silly. Don't use the email address you use on your PayPal account, or log in to the PayPal account. Just like the message states.

Comment: When i click on create account, there is no 'preconfigured'option.

Comment: Done! Updated to include the new navigation now.

Answer (score 16):

1. Create a test Business account.
2. Navigate to the Profile page of the Business account and click the Upgrade to Pro link.
3. Click Enable on the resulting screen.

**I**.

[image]

**II**.

[image]

*Note:  Once you enable PayPal Payments Pro for a test Business account, the setting is permanent and you cannot undo the configuration for that account. You create multiple Business test accounts with various settings in order to test all the variations you might need to handle with your application.*

Comment: I have upgraded my sandbox business account to pro but still I get DPRP is disabled error

Comment: I have upgrade to Business-Pro but I have also facing same issue.

Comment: @viper me too facing same issue, any idea whats the issue?

Comment: this does not work... PayPal sandbox is a mess... sometimes it works sometimes not ... no technical support .. you are on your own... create sometimes works sometimes not .. delete too... it's based on wearther forecasting ?

Answer (score 3):

To create a Sandbox test account:

**1. Log in to the Developer site (if you dont' have and id sign up first) at https://developer.paypal.com and navigate to Applications > Sandbox Accounts.**

**2. Click the Create Account button and populate the following fields:**

- Account type: Tick either the Personal or Business radio button.
- Email address: Enter a valid email address of your choosing.
  The email address doesn't need to be a real email address; the Sandbox doesn't send any email outside of the Sandbox environment. Email to Sandbox accounts, generated as a result of your test API requests, are listed on both the Notifications tab on the Developer site, as well as on the Sandbox test site.
  Use the assigned email value to reference this test account in your API calls, and to log in to the Sandbox site when you want to review the details associated with the account.
- Password: The password must be 8-20 alpha-numeric characters in length.
- First and Last names: The optional name fields accept alpha-numeric characters.
- PayPal balance: While this field is optional, it's a good idea to create test accounts with positive bank balances. Enter an integer value between 1 and 5000.
- Bank verified account: You should create both Verified and Unverified test accounts so you can fully test your application.
- Select payment card (Personal account type only): Test payments made with different payment cards by selecting either Discover or PayPal.
- Credit card type: You must select a single credit card type for each test account. The Sandbox associates a mock credit card number with the account.
- Log in with PayPal (Business account type only): Tick the **I want to add Log in with PayPal to my site** box and complete the following fields to enable testing the Log In with PayPal functionality: **Display name**, **Return URL**, **Privacy policy URL**, and **User agreement URL**
- Notes: Use the Notes field to keep track of the test account details.

**3. Click Create Account after completing the account details.**

The new test account is listed with your other test accounts on the Accounts page.

for more details visit: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ug_sandbox#accounts

Comment: The above question is about payment pro sandbox account. How to create Payments pro account in sandbox ?

Comment: To create Payments *PRO* sandbox account (as of Nov 2014),  instructions in answer from @Balaji Kandasamy worked for me

Comment: following PP instructions ? are you kidding ? their sandbox stuff does not works correctly ...

Answer (score 0):

Login to your https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/.

Click on **Accounts** under **Sandbox**.

Open Profile for the account of your business account. and click on **Upgrade to Pro**.

[image]

Hope this helps!