# Enable PayPal Website Payments Pro for my sandbox account

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

I want to enable Payments pro for my Paypal sandbox account. Does anyone know how to create  payments pro in Paypal sandbox ?

Comment: Question has been answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820298/how-to-create-paypal-website-payment-pro-sandbox-account