# no response from paypal api dodirectpayment nvp php

Tags: php, api, curl, paypal, nvp

I am attempting to set up a paypal api using the dodirectpayment NVP which I have assembled some code from online resource but when I submit it I get no response whatsoever, just a white screen. I noticed my code doesn't have any echo in it, but I am not sure how to echo whatever response paypal sends. any assistance would be great. All the customer info and credentials are all from the sandbox. Thanks!

```
  enter code here <?php 

class Paypal {
   /**
    * Last error message(s)
    * @var array
    */
   protected $_errors = array();

   /**
    * API Credentials
    * Use the correct credentials for the environment in use (Live / Sandbox)
    * @var array
    */
   protected $_credentials = array(
      'USER' => 'centerfusiondesign-test_api1.gmail.com',
      'PWD' => 'JBTYXGQHZY37RXGH',
      'SIGNATURE' => 'ANRk81o3BhdjleyZOhWslseXywLQAfcftsn6e71ykaqxRzNASgC3NYUn',
   );

   /**
    * API endpoint
    * Live - https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp
    * Sandbox - https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
    * @var string
    */
   protected $_endPoint = 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp';

   /**
    * API Version
    * @var string
    */
   protected $_version = ' 95.0';

   /**
    * Make API request
    *
    * @param string $method string API method to request
    * @param array $params Additional request parameters
    * @return array / boolean Response array / boolean false on failure
    */
   public function request($method,$params = array()) {
      $this -> _errors = array();
      if( empty($method) ) { //Check if API method is not empty
         $this -> _errors = array('API method is missing');
         return false;
      }

      //Our request parameters
      $requestParams = array(
         'METHOD' => $method,
         'VERSION' => $this -> _version
      ) + $this -> _credentials;

      //Building our NVP string
      $request = http_build_query($requestParams + $params);

      //cURL settings
      $curlOptions = array (
         CURLOPT_URL => $this -> _endPoint,
         CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,
         CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
         CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
         CURLOPT_CAINFO => dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem', //CA cert file
         CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
         CURLOPT_POST => 1,
         CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $request
      );

      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt_array($ch,$curlOptions);

      //Sending our request - $response will hold the API response
      $response = curl_exec($ch);

      //Checking for cURL errors
      if (curl_errno($ch)) {
         $this -> _errors = curl_error($ch);
         curl_close($ch);
         return false;
         //Handle errors
      } else  {
         curl_close($ch);
         $responseArray = array();
         parse_str($response,$responseArray); // Break the NVP string to an array
         return $responseArray;
      }
   }
}

$requestParams = array(
   'IPADDRESS' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
   'PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale'
);

$creditCardDetails = array(
   'CREDITCARDTYPE' => 'Visa',
   'ACCT' => '4032032109229382',
   'EXPDATE' => '012020',

);

$payerDetails = array(
   'FIRSTNAME' => 'John',
   'LASTNAME' => 'Doe',
   'COUNTRYCODE' => 'US',
   'STATE' => 'NY',
   'CITY' => 'New York',
   'STREET' => '14 Argyle Rd.',
   'ZIP' => '10010'
);

$orderParams = array(
   'AMT' => '500',
   'ITEMAMT' => '496',
   'SHIPPINGAMT' => '4',
   'CURRENCYCODE' => 'GBP'
);

$item = array(
   'L_NAME0' => 'iPhone',
   'L_DESC0' => 'White iPhone, 16GB',
   'L_AMT0' => '496',
   'L_QTY0' => '1'
);

$paypal = new Paypal();
$response = $paypal -> request('DoDirectPayment',
   $requestParams + $creditCardDetails + $payerDetails + $orderParams + $item
);

if( is_array($response) && $response['ACK'] == 'Failure') { // Payment successful
   // We'll fetch the transaction ID for internal bookkeeping
    $transactionId = $response['TRANSACTIONID'];


}


?>
```

I am a little new to PHP so hopefully my error want be too stupid, Thanks!

Comment: Is that an actual username and password in your code?

Comment: You could probably use an HTTP debugger like Fiddler to better understand the response you get.

Answer (score 1):

You seemed to have CURL peer certificate verification enabled, which you might want to disable for testing purpose until you have it setup on server.

Replace:

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
CURLOPT_CAINFO => dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem', //CA cert file
```

with:

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE,
```

Also, to check the response, just add

```
print_r($response);
```

below:

```
$response = $paypal -> request('DoDirectPayment',
   $requestParams + $creditCardDetails + $payerDetails + $orderParams + $item
);
```

Let me help you have the complete code below:

```
<?php 
class Paypal {
   /**
    * Last error message(s)
    * @var array
    */
   protected $_errors = array();

   /**
    * API Credentials
    * Use the correct credentials for the environment in use (Live / Sandbox)
    * @var array
    */
   protected $_credentials = array(
      'USER' => 'centerfusiondesign-test_api1.gmail.com',
      'PWD' => 'JBTYXGQHZY37RXGH',
      'SIGNATURE' => 'ANRk81o3BhdjleyZOhWslseXywLQAfcftsn6e71ykaqxRzNASgC3NYUn',
   );

   /**
    * API endpoint
    * Live - https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp
    * Sandbox - https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
    * @var string
    */
   protected $_endPoint = 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp';

   /**
    * API Version
    * @var string
    */
   protected $_version = ' 95.0';

   /**
    * Make API request
    *
    * @param string $method string API method to request
    * @param array $params Additional request parameters
    * @return array / boolean Response array / boolean false on failure
    */
   public function request($method,$params = array()) {
      $this -> _errors = array();
      if( empty($method) ) { //Check if API method is not empty
         $this -> _errors = array('API method is missing');
         return false;
      }

      //Our request parameters
      $requestParams = array(
         'METHOD' => $method,
         'VERSION' => $this -> _version
      ) + $this -> _credentials;

      //Building our NVP string
      $request = http_build_query($requestParams + $params);

      //cURL settings
      $curlOptions = array (
         CURLOPT_URL => $this -> _endPoint,
         CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,
         CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
         CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE,
         CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
         CURLOPT_POST => 1,
         CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $request
      );

      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt_array($ch,$curlOptions);

      //Sending our request - $response will hold the API response
      $response = curl_exec($ch);

      //Checking for cURL errors
      if (curl_errno($ch)) {
         $this -> _errors = curl_error($ch);
         curl_close($ch);
         return false;
         //Handle errors
      } else  {
         curl_close($ch);
         $responseArray = array();
         parse_str($response,$responseArray); // Break the NVP string to an array
         return $responseArray;
      }
   }
}

$requestParams = array(
   'IPADDRESS' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
   'PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale'
);

$creditCardDetails = array(
   'CREDITCARDTYPE' => 'Visa',
   'ACCT' => '4032032109229382',
   'EXPDATE' => '012020',

);

$payerDetails = array(
   'FIRSTNAME' => 'John',
   'LASTNAME' => 'Doe',
   'COUNTRYCODE' => 'US',
   'STATE' => 'NY',
   'CITY' => 'New York',
   'STREET' => '14 Argyle Rd.',
   'ZIP' => '10010'
);

$orderParams = array(
   'AMT' => '500',
   'ITEMAMT' => '496',
   'SHIPPINGAMT' => '4',
   'CURRENCYCODE' => 'GBP'
);

$item = array(
   'L_NAME0' => 'iPhone',
   'L_DESC0' => 'White iPhone, 16GB',
   'L_AMT0' => '496',
   'L_QTY0' => '1'
);

$paypal = new Paypal();
$response = $paypal -> request('DoDirectPayment',
   $requestParams + $creditCardDetails + $payerDetails + $orderParams + $item
);
print_r($response);

if( is_array($response) && $response['ACK'] == 'Failure') { // Payment successful
   // We'll fetch the transaction ID for internal bookkeeping
    $transactionId = $response['TRANSACTIONID'];
}
?>
```

Also, you might want to upgrade your sandbox business account to Pro, as refered to this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21926016/4410290

hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a blank white screen that means there's a PHP error happening but you don't have error reporting enabled.

Add this to the very top of your script.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Then run the script again and you should see the error(s).

Comment: You may also be interested in taking a look at my [PHP class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library).  It comes with fully functional samples, including DoDirectPayment, and makes it a lot easier than PayPal's SDK.