# PayPal DoDirectPayment - 10501: Invalid Configuration This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration

Tags: paypal, permissions

My API request keep failing with this error which seems to be related to a 'PayPal Payments Pro' configuration.I have read [PayPal's Configuration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_create-accounts/) which explains that i need to setup my business account to 'Payments Pro' but unable to find this feature over the business's profile, am i missing it?
Anyway im still unsure it will solve my problem, hope you could advice.

Note that i am using a developer account which has a test business account.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was solved, even though this issue seemed common, only one thread actually solved it, thanks to [Balaji Kandasamy in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820298/how-to-create-paypal-website-payment-pro-sandbox-account)

Thanks!